# Links in text are parsed differently in preview than in posted questions and answers

Tags: bug, editor

For instance, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$@.

In the preview, the link extends through the `@`, as expected, but in the posted result it ends with the `#`.

Comment: It happens on the iOS app too.

Comment: same with https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http (but not in comments, only in actual editor)